# Is there a mass registration pattern for adding a listener to multiple JComponents?

Tags: java, swing

I have a java applet that is used as a drawing tool.  Across the top of the applet I have several buttons and other widgets that allow the user to draw/modify/erase various features on the "canvas".

I have a requirement of adding some key binds that act as short cuts as well as providing some other features.  I have a key listener defined in my JPanel ( I may break it out later ).  I need all of the components on my applet to have these key binds and to do the same thing.  Currently, the only thing I know to do is to register the listener with each component.

Is this there a better design pattern/structure that I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For keys binds, don't use key listener, use **keys bindings** : [How to Use Key Bindings](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html).